# Java uncovered switch statements in a method. Does the method need to return something?

Tags: java

I'm reading some Java textbooks trying to learn a new language and I came across this method.

```
private String monthName (int month) { // bad example since this method needs to return a String
  switch (month) {
  case 1:
      return "January";
  case 2:
      return "February";
  ...

  case 12:
      return "December";
  }
}
```

The statement following this code says:

> The compiler will reject this code because it is possible to reach the
>   end with- out returning a value.

So in Java, I assume that if a method has the word "String" before the method name, it **MUST** return a String? The problem with this switch statement is that perhaps no case statement condition is satisfied and execution just drops out of the bottom? Is it necessary for methods that are not labeled to void to **ALWAYS** return a value?

Answer (score 5):

A method signature is a contract that specifies what it takes as arguments and what it is obligated to return. A method declared to return something other than void must either return something or throw something, it's not allowed to fall off the end without returning anything (if it did, the variable getting assigned the return value from the method call would still have to be assigned something).

Specifically, if a method is declared to return a String, either every possible path taken through that method must end with returning a String, returning null (null is an allowed value of any reference type), or throwing an instance of Throwable. That's what the quoted passage is telling you, the compiler can detect that you haven't done this and will complain about it.

Here you could have your code throw an exception if the integer passed in is not in the expected range. It's a good thing to have your methods validate that they are receiving reasonable values for their arguments. Using a default value or returning null is not as good because instead of exposing the problem immediately it sticks the caller with a value that may not make sense for it, and makes it harder to debug what happened because the place where the error is visible may be a long way from where the cause of the problem originated. This method could be written as:

```
private String monthName (int month) { // bad example since this method needs to return a String
  switch (month) {
  case 1:
      return "January";
  case 2:
      return "February";
  ...

  case 12:
      return "December";
  default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("found unexpected value " + month);
  }
}
```

so that the compiler won't complain, and any out-of-range values will come to your attention.

Be aware:

- There is a convention many people adhere to that advocates that all switches should contain a default case, so that unhandled cases are not passed over silently.
- The java.util Date/Calendar API numbers months from 0, not from 1 as in your example; if you use a Calendar to find a month and pass that int to this method it would be easy to return the wrong month. Error handling as near to the source as possible makes tracking down problems much easier.

Answer (score 2):

No, I think the book is referring to the fact, that the compiler will go through the Switch statement, and if it doesn't hit case 1,2 or 12, then it won't return anything at all.

Any method that has a return type, must return that type.  So in this example, you MUST return a String.

To fix that code, I'd do something like the following:

```
private String monthName (int month) { // bad example since this method needs to return a String
  String retVal = "";
  switch (month) {
  case 1:
      retVal = "January";
      break; // essential in a switch statement
  case 2:
      retVal = "February";
      break;
  case 12:
      retVal = "December";
      break;
  default:
      retVal = "Invalid Month number";
      break;
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

You may notice that I set the return value at the top of the method, then simply assign a value to it within the switch statement, then simply return the retVal at the end of the function.  That way the compiler is satisfied.  Another issue with your code sample is there are no break(s) in your switch/case block.

If that happens, then every single line would be executed regardless of which case is hit.

Answer (score 1):

```
if a method has the word "String" before the method name, it MUST return a String
```

That is almost correct, it could also return a special value,  'null'.

It is possible for method to not return a value, in this case the `String` would instead be replaced with `void`, which indicates no return value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  A method that has a return type (in this case `String`) must always return a `String`.

Interestingly in this case, it's not straightforward why there is a compiler error.  Let's simply to show why.

```
// Won't compile
String foo(boolean a) {
   if (a) {
      return "foo";
   }
}
```

This throws a compiler error because not all branches of the program return something.  It's possible to get to the end of the function (if `a` is not `true`) and still have not returned a `String`.

But it's not always the case that a method must end in a return statement.  The compiler is smart enough to realize when all branches return.

```
// Compiles
String foo(boolean a) {
   if (a) {
      return "foo";
   } else {
      return "bar";
   }
}
```

This will compile even though there is no return statement after the else because it figures out that each branch of the if/else ends in a return.

Let's move over to the switch statement.

```
// Won't compile
String foo(char c) {
   switch (c) {
      case 'a':
         return "foo";
   }
}
```

The above code will not compile, because for all inputs where `c != 'a'` there is no return statement.  But we can fix that by adding a default.

```
// Compiles
String foo(char c) {
   switch (c) {
      case 'a':
         return "foo";
      default:
         return "bar";
   }
}
```

Here for all values of c, there is a return, so the compiler doesn't complain.

Let's look at some edges cases where the compiler isn't smart enough to do branch prediction.

```
// Won't compile
String foo(char c) {
   if (c != 'a') {
      return "bar";
   }

   switch (c) {
      case 'a':
         return "foo";
   }
}
```

Compiler doesn't understand that going into the switch, 'c' must equal 'a' so even thought it might seem like this should compile it won't.

Here's a confusing case where all branches are covered, but the java compiler has still chosen to fail compilation.

```
// Won't compile
enum B { T, F }

String foo(B a) {
   switch (a) {
      case T:
         return "foo";
      case F:
         return "bar";
   }
}
```

It looks like the switch statement has all branch coverage.  There are no other instances of `B` besides `T` and `F`.  This can be solved by creating a default branch that handles new potential enum values.

Comment: Your final example is one thing I don't like about Java. The switch covers all possible cases (and if `a` were null, the switch would throw a `NullPointerException`) so the compiler shouldn't complain that it might drop off the end of the switch, because it can't.